# UWP Reorder ListView Item loses variable value

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, reorderlist

My ListView's ItemSource consits of an ObservableCollection of GamePlayerViewModels.  The CheckBox in the image sets the dealer, the arrows are a handle to move the row, the yellow button toggles a player in and out.  When I move a player that is the dealer to a new position in the list, their dealer variable becomes false.  I am not quite sure what to do to make that value stick when moving the item.

*Before Reorder*

[image: Before Reorder]

*After Reorder*

[image: After Reorder]

```
public class GamePlayerViewModel : NotificationBase
{
    private string _DisplayName;
    private bool _Dealer;
    private bool _Out;

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _DisplayName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _DisplayName, value); }
    }

    public bool Dealer
    {
        get { return _Dealer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Dealer, value); }
    }

    public bool Out
    {
        get { return _Out; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Out, value); }
    }

}
```

ListView xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock 
        Text="Dealer"/>
    <ListView
        AllowDrop="True" 
        CanReorderItems="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.GamePlayerViewModels, Converter={StaticResource GamePlayerViewModelToObjectConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate 
                x:DataType="viewModels:GamePlayerViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition 
                            Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition 
                            Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton 
                        Name="ChkDealer" 
                        Content="{x:Bind DisplayName}" 
                        GroupName="GroupDealer" 
                        IsChecked="{x:Bind Dealer, Converter={StaticResource NullableBooleanToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IsEnabled="{x:Bind Out, Converter={StaticResource OppositeNullableBooleanToBooleanConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    <StackPanel 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            IsEnabled="False"
                            Margin="0,0,5,0">
                            <SymbolIcon 
                                Symbol="Sort"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button 
                            Click="{x:Bind GamePlayerOut, Mode=OneWay}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Visibility="{x:Bind Out, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityCollapsedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <SymbolIcon 
                                Symbol="BlockContact"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            Click="{x:Bind GamePlayerIn, Mode=OneWay}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Visibility="{x:Bind Out, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityVisibleConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <SymbolIcon 
                              Symbol="AddFriend"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: How do you do the re-ordering?

Comment: Please show more detail about your `GamePlayerViewModels`.